# Can you use pre peeled garlic to make black garlic?

Tags: garlic

Is it possible to make black garlic from pre peeled garlic or is the fresh bulb imperative?

Answer (score 1):

You could experiment, but [documented recipes for black garlic](http://omniafaciat.blogspot.com/2012/12/the-black-garlic-oven-post.html) require a whole bulb.  There's also some disagreement on [whether you an make your own black garlic at home](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/30364/7180), at all.