# Black garlic: Is it possible to use a cheap rice cooker's keep warm function to make it?

Tags: fermentation, garlic, rice-cooker

I've been looking into black garlic and I read that if I take garlic and wrap it in foil and put it in a rice cooker on the keep warm function, it'll work.

I have 2 sets of cookers -- I have a pressure cooker (similar to Instant Pot) and a cheaper rice cooker ([Aroma 6-cup rice cooker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057XGM5W)). I prefer to use the Aroma rice cooker because it's smaller and I may use the pressure cooker for other things but I don't know if it has the right warm setting.

Should it still work? My concern with the small cooker is the keep warm function won't be warm enough as a traditional large rice cooker.

Comment: Please see the several answers to this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/19633/can-you-make-your-own-black-garlic?rq=1  Do any of them answer your question?

Comment: @FuzzyChef yeah I looked at them including that one -- unfortunately it's not exact. That question did have an answer mentioning the temperature needed (140°-155°F). I found the user manual of the Aroma rice cooker and it doesn't specify what temperature the keep warm setting has it set to. Also my larger question is that most traditional rice cookers are fully covered whereas the aroma rice cooker is not (it's just loosely capped with a glass lid and it isn't clear if that's okay)